# How to jquery to get elements and store in array for later use?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to gather a specific set of `<li>` elements that I'd like to use later in a loop. However, I don't seem to have the right syntax down: the debug console tells me that my object is undefined. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var all_help_triggers = [];
$(".canned-triggers > li").each(function() { all_help_triggers.push($(this)) });
all_help_triggers[0].click(function(){alert('hi!');})
```

Comment: seems to work fine here:: http://jsfiddle.net/BVrwu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
// save selected jQuery objects into variable
var all_help_triggers = $(".canned-triggers > li");

// get first element in jQuery object, and assign a click handler
all_help_triggers.eq(0).click(function(){
    alert('hi!');
});
```

**EDIT** (Based off additional comment):

To get the index, use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$('.canned-content > li').hide();

$('.canned-triggers > li').click(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.canned-content > li').eq(i).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/erp2J/11/

If you want to hide a list on page load, you should do it in CSS. Instead of:

```
$('.canned-content > li').hide();
```

remove that line and add this CSS instead:

```
.canned-content > li { display: none; }
```

Comment: .eq(): Perfect! However, now I'm trying to apply it in a loop to get each trigger to fire off its chronological equivalent in another list, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/foomarks/erp2J/8/ Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you use each() the "this" value refers to "each" element it iterates. so instead using an additional array, you should try something like that ...

```
$(".canned-triggers > li").each(function() { 
    $(this).click(function( {
       alert('hi!')
    });
});
```

Just noticed your comment:

see Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ScRqc/

```
<ul class="canned-triggers">
    <li data-element="#li1">heyo1</li>
    <li data-element="#li2">heyo2</li>
    <li data-element="#li3">heyo3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="canned-content">
    <li id="li1">I'm heyo content 1</li>
    <li id="li1">I'm heyo content 2</li>
    <li id="li2">I'm heyo content 3</li>
</ul>


$('.canned-content > li').hide();

$('.canned-triggers > li').click(function() {
    var toggleElement = $(this).data("element");
    $(toggleElement).show();
});
```

Comment: Fixed - Thank you ! :) copy paste problem :)

Comment: This is great. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to apply this in a scenario when I want a trigger to fire off its chronological equivalent in another group, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/foomarks/erp2J/8/ Is this still possible with just applying .each()?

Answer (score -1):

You should check whether your selector does return anything.

Also, an jQuery collection is array-like, what means you don't need to explicitly convert it to an array... you can loop thru it with an `for` without any problems.

However, if you still need an JavaScript array, you can do so with the following code:

```
var all_help_triggers = $.makeArray( $(".canned-triggers > li") );
```

More docs on the `$.makeArray` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)

Comment: Nice, I tried to help the user and I get a downvote with no further comments. Really nice.